# In Javafx, does mouseReleased event always happen before mouseClicked?

Tags: java, events, javafx

Which event is fired first?  Does it depend on initialization order? Does it depend on something else? What is the principle behind this?

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    doSomething();
});

pane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: You could try printing to console in those event handlers and find out which is fired first :)

Comment: I already did, but I would like an explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are actually adding an event handler to your `Node`, which handles a specific type of a `MouseEvent`. ( Have a look at [Handling JavaFX Events](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/convenience_methods.htm) as well )

If you take a look at `MouseEvent` documentation you will see :

**MOUSE_PRESSED**

`public static final EventType<MouseEvent> MOUSE_PRESSED`

> This event occurs when mouse button is pressed. This activates a
>   press-drag-release gesture, so all subsequent mouse events until the
>   button is released are delivered to the same node.

**MOUSE_RELEASED**

`public static final EventType<MouseEvent> MOUSE_RELEASED`

> This event occurs when mouse button is released. It is delivered to
>   the same node where the button has been pressed which activated a
>   press-drag-release gesture.

**MOUSE_CLICKED**

`public static final EventType<MouseEvent> MOUSE_CLICKED`

> This event occurs when mouse button has been clicked (**pressed and
>   released on the same node**). This event provides a button-like behavior
>   to any node. Note that even long drags can generate click event (it is
>   delivered to the top-most node on which the mouse was both pressed and
>   released).

So to answer your question yes, the order of events is always :

```
MOUSE_PRESSED ->  MOUSE_RELEASED -> MOUSE_CLICKED
```